# troubles with painting Menu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

I have next line in my code:

```
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

[image]

[image]

Drop menu overlaps arrow from previous menu but such behaviour absents in other applications of my OS. I have Windows 7. What is problem?(with metal look-and-feel all right)

Comment: I quickly looked at some applications on Win7 and the behavior of the submenus seems to vary.

Comment: Why do you have a different expectation? Windows explorer behaves like that in Windows 7. I would say that pretty much defines the "right way".

Comment: @Ingo Kegel, My Window explorer haven't such behaviour so it is strange...